# Netbeans and Subversion committing error

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

When I try to commit or update or do anything with the subversion inside my NetBeans 6.9.1 an error message comes up and says:

> It seems that files you are working with were created with an
>   unsupported client version. Please check out your files again with SVN
>   client 1.5.0 or later.

Please I don't know how to update or do this and also I have to work with NetBeans 6.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can still work with Netbeans; it looks like its using a version of the Subversion client that's incorrect.  Which version does it have?  It must match the version of the Subversion repository that you're communicating with.  Which version does it have?

You must either replace the Subversion plug-in in Netbeans, change the version of the Subversion repository you're talking to, or use another client like Tortoise if you're running on Windows.

I'll go against your "must use Netbeans" statement and recommend IntelliJ.  It's the best IDE on the planet, and its SVN client is superb.

Start by creating a fresh working copy of the repository with Netbeans.  Perhaps you just started with some files checked out by someone else.

Comment: First of all thank you
second I really must use netbeans "policy :("
How can I know the netbeans subversion version ?!

Comment: Whatever.  Try checking out a fresh working copy and see if that helps.

Comment: nope I tried it but nothing changed
I am using fedora 17 now , when I was using fedora 14 everything was ok but now !

Comment: Maybe you should post your question at the NetBeans forum: http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic36131.html

Comment: You could use a seperate svn client if your Netbeans svn is incompatible.

Comment: Download and install the appropriate version of Tortoise: http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, as stated in error message, used (in NB) Working Copy is in extremely old format (pre 1.5). embedded in NB  6.9 SVN-client (SVNKit) can talk with WC of 1.6 *only* (TBT!)

You can

- upgrade your WC in 1.6.x compatible format

or

- make fresh checkout in NB (will be 1.6 compatible)

In case of using external SVN clients for checkout you may get trouble, if client will be 1.7-compatible (1.7 uses WC-NG, which NetBeans 6.9 can't read also)